# Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: while starting solr

Tags: ubuntu, solr, ubuntu-14.04

I got solr 4.10.4 with a package. When i try to start solr with

```
bin/solr start
```

I get this error in file `solr-8983-console.log`

> Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException:

But the host name is in /etc/hosts with entry

```
127.0.0.1    hostname
```

I am using ubuntu `14.04 LTS`

Here `hostname` is output from

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

command

Comment: Can you share complete stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Edit hosts file. replace hostname to localhost

vim /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Then try again

Comment: In my case too, this is already added, but error still persists.

Answer (score 1):

Set [property override](https://coderanch.com/t/178539/certification/java-command-line-option-good):

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
```